# Why Firefox gives a strange result for an element with backdrop-filter combined with a fixed element with z-index?

Tags: html, css, firefox

This code gives gradient bar on top of the page in Firefox and just a blue background in Chrome (as it should be I guess).
I was unable to reproduce it on a Codepen, this behavior fires only if you open this code in a separate tab.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div style="background-image: radial-gradient(blue, red); min-height: 100vh;">
    <div style="background-color: blue; position: fixed; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; z-index: 1;"></div>
    <div style="height: 1px; backdrop-filter: blur(1px);"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect that there will be a blue background in Firefox too, but there is a visible gradient bar from the outer div for some reason. [image: the page in Firefox]

What I am actually trying to implement is a pop-over menu over the content of the page. And there is a backgrop-filter on one of the page elements so it became visible over the menu.

Comment: Which Firefox version are you running, and on what device? I've been unable to reproduce the behaviour here.

Comment: I think this is a bug in Firefox which might have been reported over here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1805879.

Comment: @bobkorinek thank you, it looks very similar

Comment: @RhysMills 108.0.1 (64-bit) on Linux

Answer (score 2):

According to [bobkorniek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17277491/bobkorinek)'s comment, yeah; it's very likely this is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1805879).

If the gradient div is not intended to be visible, you could simply remove it for a temporary fix.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body style="margin: 0;">
    <div style="background-color: blue; position: fixed; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; z-index: 1;"></div>
    <div style="height: 1px; backdrop-filter: blur(1px);"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If there's a different/more specific outcome you're looking for, you'll want to edit your question to reflect that. ^^

Comment: I've added a description of what I'm trying to achieve.